# How can I implement that in my backtracker (java)?

Tags: java, list, caching, random

I have made a small java program. An integer will be an input and then random numbers will be printed to the console till we find that integer input.
The code will cheat a bit since it will know how many digits the input number has.

Random numbers will be used and what I want to do is I want to exclude every random number that has been used. But I have no idea how it could be done. Well I have one idea but it would be a cheap bypass which I don't like. It would be by start at 0 and always increase it by 1 value till we find the input.

Could this (exclude used random number) be done in java?

I imagine we could make a list so every used number will be in that list. In every loop access the list to check if number is unused. But this is just imagination, would it really be possible in java?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Backtracker{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int counter = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter integer here: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = rand.nextInt(100)+0;
        int b = rand.nextInt(1000)+100;
        int c = rand.nextInt(10000)+1000;
        int d = rand.nextInt(100000)+10000;
        int e = rand.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
        int f = rand.nextInt(10000000)+1000000;
        int g = rand.nextInt(100000000)+10000000;

        if(x<=100){
            while(x != a){
                a = rand.nextInt(100)+0;
                System.out.println(a);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=1000){
            while(x != b){
                b = rand.nextInt(1000)+100;
                System.out.println(b);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=10000){
            while(x != c){
                c = rand.nextInt(10000)+1000;
                System.out.println(c);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=100000){
            while(x != d){
                d = rand.nextInt(100000)+10000;
                System.out.println(d);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=1000000){
            while(x != e){
                e = rand.nextInt(1000000)+100000;
                System.out.println(e);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=10000000){
            while(x != f){
                f = rand.nextInt(10000000)+1000000;
                System.out.println(f);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }

        else if(x<=100000000){
            while(x != g){
                g = rand.nextInt(100000000)+10000000;
                System.out.println(g);
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Tries: "+counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to save state somehow - for instance of what numbers you've already used. Just create a `Set<Integer>` and save your numbers there.

Comment: compare x to some sort of number it's really like cheating, integer have a range, use that range immediatly, rather than use the else if case.

Answer (score 0):

Using Random numbers doesn't sound like a good solution nor counting from 1. 
A good and simple enough solution could be:

a) Given a constraint that the input n must be 0

b) use basic [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Since this sounds like an assignment so I won't write the code for this solution.

Comment: But it's not an assignment :P I have asked that question long ago too (different question but actually same code). Only wanted know how to avoid using same numbers. If I know that, I will ask how to improve it so number will be found even faster. If I don't know myself again, will come here to ask. But again said, this is no homework.

Comment: ok, binary search will do the job and will improve the algorithm as well. If you have difficulties with the code we can help. Please accept the answer when you're happy with it.